# java error not a statement-elecricity bill

Tags: java, if-statement

This is my java code

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Ele
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int c=220,total;

        if(c<=50)
        {
            total=c*1.5;
        }

        else if(c<=100)
        {
            total=c*2;
        }

        else if(c<=200)
        {
            total=c*2.8;
        }

        else(c>300)
        {
           total=c*3;
        }

        System.out.println("Amt="+total);
    }
}
```

My two errors

```
Ele.java:20: error: not a statement
else(c>300)
    ^
Ele.java:20: error: ';' expected
else(c>300)
```

Comment: There is no boolean condition with a plain `else` statement . Replace `else(c>300)` with `else` .

Comment: Ele.java:10: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        total=c*1.5;
               ^
Ele.java:18: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        total=c*2.8;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change int to double
that is int c=220,total; to double c=220,total;

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you actually need a double for your data type, and also you need to take out the boolean condition in the else clause. Check the code below to see how this works:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // use doubles instead of ints!
        double c = 220.0;
        double total = 0.0;

        if(c <= 50.0) {
            total=c*1.5;
        }
        else if(c <= 100.0) {
            total = c * 2.0;
        }
        else if(c <= 200.0) {
            total = c * 2.8;
        }
        // no boolean needed for "else" conditions
        else {
            total = c * 3.0;
        }

        System.out.println("Amt = " + total);
    }
}
```